# MySQL Generated columns on non-deterministic function

Tags: mysql, optimization

ON MySQL 5.7, generated columns are not allowed with non-deterministic function.

The query that I need to optimize is executing on a bulky table.

Where clause is causing a full scan on the table, need to optimize that.

The column is DateTime type, we have to use the unix_timestamp function as per application

WHERE **UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Last_Used_Time)** >  1540874005

I am trying to convert UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Last_Used_Time) into a generated column but throws an error disallowed function used in the expression.

Any workaround to allow MySQL to use generated/virtual column with unix_timestamp function.

Comment: You are barking up a specific tree.  Let's back up and see if there is _another_ way to solve the problem.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the query that is so slow.

Comment: *The column is DateTime type* If so why you use timezone-dependent function? If you know datetime you want to compare with - why you do not compare with datetime literal immediately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't convert the column's value, convert your criterium:

```
WHERE Last_Used_Time > from_unixtime(1540874005)
```

Comment: That's brilliant, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Hi Gerard, I tried as per your suggestion, query execution time reduces from 4 min to 4 seconds, so query seem optimized,  but on comparing records, I am finding the records obtained from before and after query vary slightly. Few records are not matching, not sure why so, any reason that you are aware of?

Comment: Please show last_used_time from a number of matching and no longer matching records (in your question please).

Comment: Hey Gerard, figured out the issue was, misunderstanding of data from our end.
Anyways Thanks for your support.

Comment: It's been a pleasure.